# Invalid or unexpected token when a div is appended jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a div(dynamically created) inside a div. I get this error when i append a div. But if i try to append a string it works without any issue. I dont understand the reason behind this. I don't see anything wrong with my syntax as well. The below one cause error

```
$("#scheduled_bar_panel_col").append(
 "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8' id = 'panel_column'>
 </div>"
);
```

But this works perfect

```
$("#scheduled_bar_panel_col").append(
"Hello"
);
```

Let me know what is the reason behind this and how to solve this

Comment: string in multiple line ???check your console .....  make it single line....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `""` doesn't support multi lines. Use `` for them if you use modern JavaScript `ES6` **[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility)**

```
`<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8' id = 'panel_column'>
 </div>`
```

Or use to separates `strings` and concatenate them.

```
"<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8' id = 'panel_column'>" +
"</div>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `+` symbol at the end of line:

```
$("#scheduled_bar_panel_col").append(
  "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8' id = 'panel_column'>" +
  "</div>"
);
```